# How to refer to hierachical column in a pandas query?

Tags: python, pandas

```
# hierarchical indices and columns
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014], [1, 2]],
                                   names=['year', 'visit'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bob', 'Guido', 'Sue'], ['HR', 'Temp']],
                                     names=['subject', 'type'])

# mock some data
data = np.round(np.random.randn(4, 6), 1)
data[:, ::2] *= 10
data += 37

# create the DataFrame
health_data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
health_data
```

How can I get all rows that are using `pd.query`:

1. Bob HR > 35
2. *any* subjects HR > 35

If this is not possible with `pd.query` at the moment, this would be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use MultiIndexes with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

*(Well, you can to some limit use `health_data.query('@health_data.Bob.HR > 35')`, but this has many flaws, and you won't be able to do this with a sublevel only).*

You can use [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) instead to select your levels:

```
# is Bod/HR > 35?
m1 = health_data[('Bob', 'HR')].gt(35)
# is any HR > 35?
m2 = health_data.xs('HR', level='type', axis=1).gt(35).any(axis=1)

# keep rows with both conditions
out = health_data.loc[m1&m2]
```

output:

```
subject      Bob       Guido         Sue      
type          HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp
year visit                                    
2013 1      42.0  38.0  45.0  37.7  33.0  36.9
     2      48.0  38.2  42.0  36.2  21.0  35.9
2014 2      50.0  39.2  44.0  36.0  36.0  35.8
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew about the `.xs` approach, and was suspecting that `pd.query` can't handle this.